# Duality and tensor product of the Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I would like to know how to compute the tensor product of the matrices below and how to deal with duality of vector spaces.

The vector space I concern is the Lie algebra $\mathscr{sl_2}$ with basis $\{H, E, F\}$ and whose bracket is given by $[H, E]=2E, [H, F]=-2F, [E,F]=H$.
With respect to this basis, the Killing form $B:\mathscr{sl_2}\otimes \mathscr{sl_2} \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0& 0 &4\\
0 & 8& 0 \\
4&0&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

What I am confused is the following computations.

We regard $B$ as an element in $(\mathscr{sl_2})^*\otimes (\mathscr{sl_2})^*$. (How?)

Then the dual element of $B$ is given by
$$\begin{bmatrix} E & H& F \end{bmatrix}\otimes \begin{bmatrix}0& 0 &4\\
0 & 8& 0 \\
4&0&0 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} E\\H\\F \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{4}E\otimes F+\frac{1}{8}H\otimes H+ \frac{1}{4} F\otimes E.$$
I would like to know why the element on the left hand side of the equation is the dual of $B$. Also I would like to know how to show this equality.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the dual basis to $(E,F,H)$ with respect to the Killing form is just given by $(F/4,E/4,H/8)$. This follows directly from the definition of a dual basis $(b_i^*)$ to a basis $(b_i)$ with respect to a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form. You can see this from the matrix of the Killing form.
Hence the Casimir operator $C=C_B=\sum_i b_i\otimes b_i^*$ is given by
$$
C=\frac{E\otimes F}{4}+\frac{F\otimes E}{4}+\frac{H\otimes H}{8}.
$$

Comment: I guess the Casimir operator $C$ you mentioned is the dual of $B$. (I am not familiar with it.) In my setting, $B\in (\mathrm{sl_2})^*\otimes (\mathrm{sl_2})^*$. So why $C$ can be written as $\sum_i b_i \otimes b_i^*$?

Comment: Yes, this is the same. It is an element of $sl(2)\otimes sl(2)^{\ast}$ by definition, i.e., of the form $\sum_ib_i\otimes b_i^{\ast}$. Remember, we have the basis $(b_i)$ and the dual basis $(b_i^*)$ relative to the Killing form. You have one dual $*$ too much, by the way.